# why a collection exists but can not find in show collections?

Tags: mongodb

In the mongo shell, I can find records from collection `stat` by using such commands:

```
use gm;
gm.stat.find({});
```

but `stat` is not listed in show collection results.

Comment: Can you rename the collection and try? `stats` is a reserved name as it is used for a function, so stat might be used for something else

Comment: Your command is already not correct, as it's ``db.stat.find({})`` and not ``gm.stat.find({});``

Comment: my command actually is use gm; db.stat.find({});

Comment: I run db.createDataCollection('stat');  mongo return {"OK" : 0, "errmsg" : "collection already exists"}; I run db.getCollectionNames().indexOf('stat')   result is -1.

Comment: I am running: `use gm` and `db.stat.insert({})` Then, both db.getCollectionNames() and `show collections` show me the collection `stat`

Answer (score 1):

Any collection virtually exists all the time (i.e. you will not get an error saying that "you did not create a collection"). As soon as you insert the first document into a collection this will exist also physically (will be created on the disk). So if you really want to make sure a collection exists use:

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

This will show you only the collections that had at least one document inserted into them, even if they are currently empty.

Once physically created, a collection can be deleted using the `drop` command:

```
db.myColl.drop()
```

This will delete it physically but the "virtual" one will still be there.

As for your example, running:

```
db.stat.insert({}); print("Collection stat exists:" + (db.getCollectionNames().indexOf("stat") !== -1));
```

will tell you:

```
Collection stat exists: true
```

Comment: He says he has records in his collection. Atleast that's what the question sounds like.

Comment: I also have the same issue. but mine is bit strange I can see my collection in localhost but not in remote ip. When i use show collection in local it gives me collection name but in remote IP it is not showing anything..Someone please help